# How can I create 10*10 buttons on slack slash API.

Tags: json, slack, slack-api

I try to make a 10*10 grid on slack to build interactive events but its giving me a grid of 5*5 is there any other way through loop that I can achieve this

Comment: Please provide anything you've done so far.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how the Slack UI works. You have no control over the positioning of your buttons on Slack, other then in which order they appear. Also note that it will look different on other platforms, e.g. web vs. mobile. This is a feature of Slack, which is meant to be platform agnostic.

Also, each attachment can have a maximum of 5 buttons. However, if you want to display more buttons you can just create additional attachments with additional buttons in the same message.